# File iteration with the preprocessor

Tags: preprocessor, boost-preprocessor, preprocessor-meta-program

Am I correct that boost's file recursion requires that the file using the recursion must be in the include path?

I don't see it anywhere in the documentation, but I just debugged a problem where this seems to be the case.  This makes using this as a means to generate boilerplate code automatically somewhat limited when used for a library as the library header file may not be in the include path.

Any comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to be true.  So I wrote a library to deal with this situation.  Here it is if anyone else is having the same problem:  https://sourceforge.net/projects/relativeiterate/